# Capacitor discharge ignition system in electric vehicles

Tags: electrical, ignition

[Capacitor discharge ignition system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_discharge_ignition)

[CDI video](https://youtu.be/0yK3Opq_i0M)

Can capacitor discharge ignition system be used in electric vehicles viz Cars, Motorbikes etc?

Answer (score 2):

No. EV's don't use or need them. Capacitive discharge ignition systems are for internal combustion engines (ICE). EV's don't have an ICE.

Comment: Thanks. Which type of automobiles  will have a CDI system? Racing cars? Military vehicles?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar - Capacitive discharge was used prior to electronic ignition systems in distributors with points.

Comment: Thanks. You mean old cars?. CDI is replaced by electronic?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar - It is an example.